# Stackblitz - adding options to angular generator?

Tags: stackblitz

Trying to run through the Hall of Heroes tutorial. Generating components, services, etc, all see fine when using the angular generator - select the type, enter the name.

But when getting to creating the routing files, the command to be entered, if using the command line, is:

```
ng generate module app-routing --flat --module=app
```

So I opened up the generator, selected module, and tried entering "app-routing --flat --module=app" but the options were ignored - "app-routing" was created in a folder, and not in the root.

So (how) can I pass options to the generator?